# Numerological seqience

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Hi I am developing an android app ... related to numerology .. where I need to calculate the corresponding value of current number.. First I will give information about how to calculate it.. In numerology each letter have its own value. That values are giving below.

```
A-1,B-2,C-3,D-4,E-5,F-6,G-7,H-8,I-9
J-1,K-1,L-3,M-4,N-5,O-6,P-7,Q-8,R-9
S-1,T-2,U-3,V-4,W-5,X-6,Y-7,Z-8
```

and my problem is I need to display the current working number of a person from year 2012 to 2022. It is calculated like this. If suppose my name Jocheved and my Date of birth is 12-02-1988 then on 1988 my letter is J, because that is my first letter of my Firstname and value J according to above table is 1 so the effect of J in my life is for 1 year ie, from 1988 to 1989 and my next letter is O, its value is 6. So the effect of O will last for 6 years ie, from 1989 to 1995 and from 1996 effect of C will start and it will go like that once the letter finished then it will start again from the starting letter in my case ie, J.

In my program I need to display the effective letter of person from 2012 to 2022 . I developed a programme and I can display the values from my DOB to 2022 but I need only from the year 2012 . that means it should be like 
2012 - X
2013 -X Like that .. I am giving my code below.. if anybody can help.. pls help

```
tv23.setText(getValueCycle2(2022));

private CharSequence getValueCycle2(int endYear) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int c = 0;
                String out = "FName\n\n";
                char[] cycle = getLetterCycle();

                if(birthYear + 1 > endYear)
                {
                    return "";
                }

                for (int i = birthYear + 1; i <= endYear ; i++)
                {               
                    out += cycle[c] + "\n";
                    Log.v(TAG, "i - " + i + " : c - " + c + " : cycle(c) - " + cycle[c]);
                    c++;
                    if (c == cycle.length)
                    {
                        c = 0;
                    }

                }

                return out;
            }

            private char[] getLetterCycle() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int value;
                char ch;
                String str = "";

                for (int i = 0; i < fName.length(); i++)
                {
                    ch = fName.charAt(i);
                    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
                    {
                        value = letterValue(ch);
                        for (int j = 0; j < value; j++)
                        {
                            str += ch;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return str.toCharArray();
            }

            private int letterValue(char c) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (c < 65 || c > 90)
                {
                    return 0;
                }

                int v = (c - 64) % 9;
                return v == 0 ? 9 : v;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your question. If you just want to print output from 2012, you just need two things:

Change the method signature to'

```
private static CharSequence getValueCycle2(int startYear, int endYear)
```

Change the Log.v to

```
    if (i >= startYear) {
         Log.v(TAG, "i - " + i + " : c - " + c + " : cycle(c) - " + cycle[c]);

    }
```

Call the method as

```
tv23.setText(getValueCycle2(2012,2022));
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: How to give this start year in calculation

Comment: Now I am getting the values from 2012 only but a problem is there I am getting value from the starting letter like J .. but J should start from 1988 - but here the calculation is starting from 2012

Comment: the if condition of 2012 is just for printing. I am not sure why that will impact your algorithm?